# responsive css vertical divider

Tags: css, divider

Im creating a responsive table which contains a vertical divider. I want that divider to move along with the text according to all screen sizes. left and right td are responsive just the divider is creating problem.

The CSS is

```
.divider{
position: absolute;
left:30.5%;
top:6%;
bottom:25%;
border-left:2px solid #333;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

and the related html is

```
<table width="100%">
<tr> 
<td>
this is test
</td>
<td><div class="divider"></div></td>
<td>
This is test2
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The problem is when I change the position from absolute to anything else in css it hides the divider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case....its happening because i feel that your are giving position only to the div and not the containing `<td>`....give this parent `td` a position first

add height, width to `html`,`body` and your are good to go...

[**solution**](http://jsfiddle.net/n5u73/)

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    height:100%; /* added */
    width:100%;/* added */
}
.divider {
    position: relative; /* changed*/
    left:30.5%;
    top:6%;
    bottom:25%;
    border-left:2px solid #333;
    overflow:hidden;
}
td.r {
    position:absolute;/* added */
    height:100%;/* added */
    width:100%;/* added */
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table width="100%" border=1>
    <tr>
        <td>this is test</td>
        <td class="r">       <!-- notice the added class-->
            <div class="divider"></div>
        </td>
        <td>This is test2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**EDIT**

A much simpler and cleaner way to create divider is to use `td` only for divider, not the `div`....[**check this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/n5u73/1/)

Remove the `div` creating the divider and instead, add the `divider` class to `td` itself!

```
<table width="100%" border=0>
    <tr>
        <td>this is test</td>
        <td class="divider"></td>
        <td>This is test2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
td {
    text-align:center
}
td.divider {
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    width:1px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    background:#000;
}
```

Comment: Sorry brother it didnt worked. I already have tried it. When I change the position of divider it totally disappears.

Comment: have u tried giving `position` to  containing `td`...in my demo it works!!

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses bro. That also didnt worked. Kindly check the preview link I have shared in the main thread.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44676/discussion-between-noobeditor-and-bangash)